# Application startup failed

Tags: spring, spring-websocket

After using websocket, my project stopped running, I can not understand what was happening, maybe the dependencies need to be updated?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSocketEventListener': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'messagingTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerMessagingTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate]: Factory method 'brokerMessagingTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerChannel' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractSubscribableChannel]: Factory method 'brokerChannel' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientInboundChannel' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractSubscribableChannel]: Factory method 'clientInboundChannel' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/log/LogDelegateFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractSubscribableChannel]: Factory method 'clientInboundChannel' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/log/LogDelegateFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
... 81 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/log/LogDelegateFactory
at org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpLogging.forLog(SimpLogging.java:67) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.AbstractMessageBrokerConfiguration.clientInboundChannel(AbstractMessageBrokerConfiguration.java:130) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b2def8a5.CGLIB$clientInboundChannel$19(<generated>) ~[spring-websocket-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b2def8a5$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6db52c62.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-websocket-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b2def8a5.clientInboundChannel(<generated>) ~[spring-websocket-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
... 82 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.log.LogDelegateFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
... 94 common frames omitted
```

As I understand it is impossible to create beans

Comment: Seems to me a classpath problem. What's the content of your pom.xml? What changes you made when added the websocket?

Comment: i add my dependences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try include this?

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>your spring web version</version>
</dependency>
```